# Java TCP socket want to multiple times input with one connection

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I want to implement interactive chatbot system with java TCP socket Programming.

I search basic Java TCP example in google, base code is this.

**Client Side**

```java
// Client side

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class EasyTCPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 20532;
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                String realStr = "This is woolbro dev Test";
                out.write(realStr.getBytes());
                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                String time = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println(time);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Side**

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;

public class EasyTCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 20532;
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("[ "+socket.getInetAddress()+" ] client connected");
                OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
                writer.println(new Date().toString());

                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                System.out.println("###### msg : "+reader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

then, I change my code to success of this statement

> TCP client will ‘connect’ only once at the beginning of the program. After that, even if the menu
> repeats, it simply uses that same connection.

I understand that statement is follows:
**Create one socket, and use that socket, client send many times to server without close connection.**

so I change my client side code follows..

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class EasyTCPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 20532;
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) { // <------ change two line
            while (true) {                                  // <---- change two line
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                String realStr = "This is woolbro dev Test";
                out.write(realStr.getBytes());
                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                String time = reader.readLine();

                System.out.println(time);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but this approach doesn't work correctly. client wait reader.readLine function infinitly.
which point I missed in that approach? I appreicated with your questions.
Thankyou

I search basic Java TCP example in google, base code is this.

I search socket.setKeepAlive(true) option. but doesn't work.

and I search thread's approach, but this approach support to multiple client
I wanna support only one clinet, and this client has multiple write to server using for loop without close connection in socket.

Comment: Use the same `BufferedReader` for the life of the socket.

Comment: Thank you. But still doesn't work